# Diagnostics data was not saved to the credential store

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oim

While starting Weblogic server I am getting following error.

Info: Data source is: opss-DBDS
[EL Severe]: 2015-06-09 11:16:36.84--ServerSession(357148745)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified

Error Code: 17002
Jun 9, 2015 11:16:36 AM                                                            oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStore init
WARNING: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreConnectivityException: JPS-10000: There was an internal error in the policy store.
JPS-01055: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreConnectivityException: JPS-10000: There was an internal error in the policy store.
Error: Diagnostics data was not saved to the credential store.
Error: Validate operation has failed.
Need to do the security configuration first!

Answer (score 1):

Check with following WLST command to create/validate the credential store.

$MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh $OIM_HOME/common/tools/configureSecurityStore.py –d $DOMAIN_HOME -c IAM -p  -m validate

if above command successfully validated then there will be issue with DB host. If not then just removed validate and put create and create a credential store entry.

It'll resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of the opss-DBDS data source.  It looks like the connection pool has an invalid hostname in the URL: "Unknown host specified".